# querying nanostoreinmotion from method

Tags: rubymotion

When using RubyMotion I have a database created using NanoStoreInMotion. I am able to query on the database with the user parameters but if the phone number is not valid it throws an error and breaks my application. My question is, if I am trying to write my if/else statement to read as if the phone variable is valid "login", elsif "throw an alert view", what am I missing on the elsif part? The official login part works.

```
def main_login
  phone = @login_field.text
  user = User.find(:phone_number => "#{phone}")


  if user[0].phone_number == phone
    controller = UserLoggedInController.alloc.initWithUser(@user)
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
  elsif user == []
    prompt = UIAlertView.alloc.initWithTitle("Checked In",
                  message: "Not a valid login",
                  delegate: nil,
                  cancelButtonTitle: "Close",
                  otherButtonTitles: nil)   
  prompt.show

  end 
end
```

Comment: Hi again, Jason :) This is actually a very simple one, you just need to check for user.count>0 before starting your logic. A missing number means that the result will be an empty array.

Comment: Adrian. Thank you for that. I wrapped my logic in another if statement that counted before doing the logic and it worked. if user.count > 0 #if statement. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue on your logic.

The following piece of code should work.

```
def main_login
  phone = @login_field.text
  users = User.find(:phone_number => "#{phone}")

  if users == nil or users == []
    prompt = UIAlertView.alloc.initWithTitle("Checked In",
                  message: "Not a valid login",
                  delegate: nil,
                  cancelButtonTitle: "Close",
                  otherButtonTitles: nil)   
    prompt.show
  elsif users[0].phone_number == phone
    controller = UserLoggedInController.alloc.initWithUser(users[0])
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
  end 
end
```